# Can Mapbox legends / overlay boxes be displayed differently when viewed on mobile devices?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I created a webmap using Mapbox GL JS for my website. In a desktop browser, it looks exactly the way that I want it to look. When I load it on a mobile device, the information box and legend are too wide and take up too much of the map area. Is there a way to make them display smaller when loaded on a mobile device?

Answer (score 2):

As per general design practice, it would be better if you use a button to alternatively show or hide the legend on mobile devices, instead of making the legend smaller.
If you are using jQuery, it would be like the following:

```
<button type="button" onclick="toggleLegend();">Legend</button>


var showLegend = true;
var toggleLegend = function(){
        if(showLegend === true){
           $('.legend').hide(); 
           showLegend = false; 
        }else{
           $('.legend').show();
           showLegend = true; 
        }
    }
```

However, if you don't want to use the approach, you can use css media queries to change the size of the legend. Check this [example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/custom-legend/). In *style* block, add the following

```
#legend{max-width: 100px}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
   #legend{max-width: 100px}
}
```